# Mixed effect models: comparison by group and time point for repeated measurements in only one of the two groups

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am looking to perform a mixed effect model analysis to explain the variation of an outcome variable (score Y) in two groups (patients & controls) in an observational study. There is no external intervention, but all patient are recruited at onset of their disease (heart attack for example). Patients have undergone measurements at three timepoints, but controls only at one time point, as we assume there is no variation over time in controls. Measurements for controls and patients were not done at the same time, so time point is a relative variable for each subject (for time of recruitment to the measurements), however for all subjects the interval between timepoints was the same (ie. patients had a measure at 0 days, 30 days and 90 days and controls only at 0 days).

Therefore I am looking to find if for the outcome variable:

- There is an overall difference between the two groups
- There is a difference between timepoints
- There is a difference between patients at every time point vs for controls (eg: patients at time point 1 vs controls, patients at time point 2 vs controls, etc ...)

Sample tabular extract:

| score Y | group | time point | subject-id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.4 | patient | 0 | 0 |
| 0.2 | patient | 1 | 0 |
| 0.3 | patient | 2 | 0 |
| 0.4 | control | 0 | 1 |
| 0.5 | control | 0 | 2 |

Is it possible to address these questions with a single model?

I am trying to formulate it through the `lme4` package in R and I am unsure how to specify this exactly.

Comment: Please provide more info by editing the question. What is being measured ? What is the intervention ? Were all controls measured at the same time ? If you want to compare subjects at different time points why were they not measured at the same time ?  Do you want to assume that the controls had the same response at the follow up times as at baseline ?

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly. In brief, we measure score Y for healthy controls and patients that had an heart attack. Subjects have their measures relative to the moment of their recruitment into the study protocol which depends on time their event occurred, so it was not possible to measure all at the same time. We assume controls have no variation over time.